# После перезагрузки страницы не скролило вверх

Tags: javascript, jquery

Например я листаю длинный лендинг и на середине перезагрузил страницу, то как сделать, чтобы после перезагрузке я вернулся автоматом на место, на котором остановился, а не на начало страницы?

Comment: Разве браузеры не имеют такое поведение "из коробки"?

Comment: Браузеры по-умолчанию так делают. Это какие-то скрипты у вас скролят страницу. Возможно расширения браузера.

Comment: Можно поставить костыль и запоминать положение скролла в куках или в локальном хранилище

Comment: та вот два одинаковых сайта по разному работают. Один, через локалхост, не запоминает, а второй нормально

Comment: Да, проверил, дело в браузере. Хрому что-то мешает. В других нормально работает. Спасибо